# "Format" same as "Restore/Reset to Factory settings"?

Tags: formatting, restore

Can someone tell me the definition/process of "Formatting" and "Restore to Factory Settings"? are these two the same thing?

(I don't think those tags are right. If not, can someone please attach the correct ones?)

Comment: Where are you seeing these two options? The latter (restore) on an OEM system generally means it will reinstall the OS, drivers, OEM shovelware, other bundled crapware etc. just as it was when you bought the PC. A format on the other hand will empty your hard disk/partition of data (well technically it might not depending on the type of format, but that's a different issue).

Comment: @Karan, I have seen it on a mobile device before, and I wanted to know the difference, or if there is one.

Comment: Mobile related questions are off-topic here, and while restore would mean basically the same thing, I'm not sure what a format option is supposed to do on a phone.

Comment: @Karan can this apply to a PC/Mac? (I.e. being able to format *or* Restore to Factory Settings?)

Comment: See my first comment above. It definitely applies to OEM systems that have a manufacturer provided recovery image/partition.

Comment: Your confusion may have come from a reference to formatting restoring a hard disk to its original condition (which is empty). Formatting clears the content from a hard drive. The computer manufacturers start with an empty hard drive and write an image to it that contains everything they supply with the computer. After you get it, you customize it, update it, load other software, etc. If you later run into a problem that can't easily be fixed, restoring to factory settings puts everything back the way it was from the factory. If the hardware is working, that puts it back to a working baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A format will completely wipe the target, deleting everything on it. If you do it securely, the whole drive will be written over with zeros. A factory reset only deletes all user-data and settings, while keeping the operating system intact. I hope this is what you were looking for.